# Mysql Many to Many Query

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I have a many to many table setup in my mysql database. Teams can be in many games and each game has 2 teams. There is a table in between them called teams_games. SHOW CREATE TABLE information follows.

I have been messing with this query for a while. At this point I don't care if it requires sub-queries, joins, or unions. I have tried all of them but nothing has been satisfactory and I think i'm missing something. The disconnect I keep having is finding the two team ids from each game and then using the tid to grab the team information.

What I would like to do is if given a game id (gid) I can query to find:

home_team_name, home_team_id, away_team_name, away_team_id, team_league(away and home will be the same league), all the information from games table

`Table  Create Table`

```
 teams  CREATE TABLE `teams` (
 `tid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`league` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`tid`)
```

)

`CREATE TABLE teams_games (`

```
`tid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`gid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`homeoraway` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`tid`,`gid`),
KEY `gid` (`gid`),
CONSTRAINT `teams_games_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tid`) REFERENCES `teams` (`tid`),
CONSTRAINT `teams_games_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`gid`) REFERENCES `games` (`gid`)
```

)

`CREATE TABLE games (`

```
`gid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`location` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`time` datetime NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
`error` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
`home_score` smallint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`away_score` smallint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`gid`)
```

)

Comment: Tried different subqueries and joins. Pieced together code from online and guessed my way through it but without success. My question was already long so I didn't want to fill it up with more stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed homeoraway = 1 for home and homeoraway = 0 for away.

```
SELECT g.*, ht.name, ht.tid, at.name, at.tid, ht.league
FROM games g
JOIN team_games htg ON htg.gid = g.gid AND htg.homeoraway = 1
JOIN team ht ON ht.tid = htg.tid
JOIN team_games atg ON atg.gid = g.gid AND atg.homeoraway = 0
JOIN team at ON at.tid = atg.tid
```

This works by joining games to team_games for the home team, then to teams for the team info, then doing the same thing for the away team.

Comment: those from the original revision of your answer.  now that you've changed them to inner joins, i've reverted the -1.  oh, and regarding your "counter-downvotes": you're my hero.

Comment: This worked great, is very succinct, and understandable. You did leave out the WHERE clause at the end for the g.gid but that was obvious how to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just drop the `teams_games` table and alter `games`:

```
CREATE TABLE games (

 `gid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`location` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`time` datetime NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
`error` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
`home_score` smallint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`away_score` smallint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`home_tid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`away_tid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`gid`)
)
```

Then you can write a simple join like:

```
SELECT 
    g.*, 
    h.name as home_team, 
    a.name as away_team, 
    h.league as league 
FROM games AS g 
    INNER JOIN teams AS h ON g.home_tid = h.tid
    INNER JOIN teams as a ON g.away_tid = a.tid
WHERE gid = ?
```

Comment: The simplest solution, because a game can only ever have, and must have 2 teams involved. This isn't a many-to-many situation, it's a many-to-two situation, so no need for the intermediate joining table at all

Comment: The reason I did it this way is because i'm trying to be a good sql citizen and get the hang of the whole many-to-many thing. So yes, I am making it more difficult that it needs to be in this situation and was going to do that initially but decided against it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  th.name as home_team_name,
  th.tid as home_team_id,
  ta.name as away_team_name,
  ta.tid as away_team_id,
  th.league as team_league,
  g.* 
from games g
  inner join teams_games tgh on (g.gid = tgh.gid and tgh.homeoraway = <HOME_VALUE>)
  inner join teams_games tga on (g.gid = tga.gid and tga.homeoraway = <AWAY_VALUE>)
  inner join teams th on (tgh.tid = th.tid)
  inner join teams ta on (tga.tid = ta.tid)
where
  g.gid = <GAME_ID>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that 1 = home, 2 = away. You can change appropriately.

```
SELECT
    HT.name AS home_team_name,
    HT.tid AS home_team_id,
    AT.name AS away_team_name,
    AT.tid AS away_team_id,
    HT.league AS team_league
FROM
    teams_games HTG
INNER JOIN teams_games ATG ON
    ATG.gid = HTG.gid AND
    ATG.homeoraway = 2
INNER JOIN teams HT ON
    HT.tid = HTG.tid
INNER JOIN teams AT ON
    AT.tid = ATG.tid
WHERE
    HTG.gid = ???
    HTG.homeoraway = 1
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks tom. I chose Marcus' answer only because it was clearer and more succinct.